# While loop in python allowing only one of two responses

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that I want to restrict on one of two answers. One would continue the loop and the other would break out of it. The catch is that the code is similar to the following:

```
choice = "y"
while choice == "y":
    if condition:
        print ("something")
    choice = input("continue?")
```

I want to allow only y or n answers all else should prompt again. Please help. I have found several things close, but when I try I get an infinite loop for the prompt.

Comment: To be completely honest, this looks more like asking for someone to do your homework. If this is an honest question, you may want to check the keyword "break" and the "if/else" statements in a python tutorial.

Comment: If it were homework I would ask an instructor to help me. But I am teaching myself Python. I just happen to come across a part where I got stuck and can't solve what I am wanting to do, without help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `while True` .The loop won't stop until it receives the input 'Y' or 'N' from the user.Try this :

```
while True:
        choice = input('continue?')
        if choice =='Y' or choice =='N':
            print(choice )
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Maybe I should be a little more clear. If the user answers Y then I want it to run the code (where it says print something) again. If the user answers N I want it to end the program. All other responses should cause the prompt to repeat until a valid entry is given.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `sentinel controlled program`. The loop will keep asking until you type in the flag value, 'no'.

```
while (c != 'no'):
    ...     c = input("continue?")
    ...     if 2 > 1:
    ...             print('It is')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It accepts yes/Yes/YES/Y/y/No/NO/no/n/N

```
valid=['Y','N']
while True:
        choice = str(raw_input('continue?'))
        if choice.upper()[0] in valid:
            print(choice)
            print ("Write your code here")
            break
        else:
            continue
```